Why this coin is on the solana or phantom even?
I did some digging, and it turns out the developer of CABAL Token holds more than 70% of the total supply
Why this is a problem:
Market manipulation risk: With such a huge portion of the supply, the dev can easily dump their tokens on unsuspecting buyers, tanking the price.

No decentralization: This goes completely against the principles of crypto. If one person controls that much, it's basically a centralized scam disguised as a token.

No transparency: There’s little to no info about the team or the project roadmap, which screams rug pull potential.

Here’s a post by a blockchain security expert explaining why it’s a scam: https://x.com/StalkHQ/status/1866144176250790376
and another link: https://x.com/CryptoRugMunch/status/1867280558654365751
Edit
As someone pointed out in the comments, their last rug pull was $Hotdoge
Added some imgur photo for volume manipulation: https://imgur.com/a/W40LYfC
